# Python: Creating variables/dataframe names from strings elements of a list

Tags: python, string, dataframe

stack overflow and python beginner here!

I have a list called var1 with string elements which i want to use them as dataframe names

```
var1 = ['df_surname_lastname1', 'df_surname_lastname2',......]
```

how can i use each individual element as dataframe name/variable?

the code is like

```
for item in var1:
   item = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet2')
   item.head()
```

which should crate dataframes with the names of the elements in the list

Thanks and Regards
Oz

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a dictionary of dataframes with the key being the desired name.

```
df_dict = {}
list_of_names = ['df_surname_lastname1', 'df_surname_lastname2',......]
for i in list_of_names:
   df_dict[i] = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet2')
   df_dict[i].head()
```

You can then call this dataframe with the key:

```
print(df_dict['df_surname_lastname1'])
```

### Warning:

The fact you are keeping the `path` and `sheet_name` parameters constant in the loop means that you will always get the same data only with different names. I don't know if this is your expected behavior, but I just thought it'd be good to let you know in advance.

Comment: thanks, i am aware of your warning, i actually have another "for loop" which cycles over another list of filenames. Since filenames are strings, it does not create an issue.

Comment: Sure, I hope this answer solves what you were looking for!